# Inverse of the cumulative function of a lognormal distribution in C++

Tags: c++, inverse, cdf

I'm looking for a function implementation (or library) in C++ that could calculate the value of the inverse of the cumulative function of a lognormal distribution. I had no luck finding it.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Scientific Library [can do that](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Lognormal-Distribution.html), and it's a plain C library available on pretty much any system. From the documentation:

> - Function: `double gsl_cdf_lognormal_P (double x, double zeta, double sigma)`
> - Function: `double gsl_cdf_lognormal_Q (double x, double zeta, double sigma)`
> - Function: `double gsl_cdf_lognormal_Pinv (double P, double zeta, double sigma)`
> - Function: `double gsl_cdf_lognormal_Qinv (double Q, double zeta, double sigma)`
>
>   These functions compute the cumulative distribution functions P(x), Q(x) and their inverses for the lognormal distribution with
>     parameters zeta and sigma.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you.
EDIT : By the way, I found out that the Boost library can do that too (these inverse cumulative functions are actually also called "quantile functions", which I didn't know.)

Answer (score 0):

The Numerical Recipes 3rd edition has a section on this. You can read 30 pages per month for free and unlimited when you subsribe [here](http://www.nr.com/oldverswitcher.html). The lognormal distribution is discussed in section 6.14.7 page 328.